# iphonesdk nsmutable array object issue

Tags: iphone

I have a mutable array named `Namearray` which contains 7-8 objects.

I wanted to check if it contains 0 object then I will display alert view.

What should I write to check that `Namearray` contains zero object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ([NameArray count] == 0)
{
  // show alertview
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry just checked and found it out myself. If any one looking for the answer:

```
if(NameArray.count == 0)
{
    UIAlertView *baseAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                              initWithTitle:@"" 
                              message:@"You have missed a place, write everything please....."
                              delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil
                              otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil]; 
    [baseAlert show];       
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use array.count then your problem will be solve....

Comment: `count` is not a property, so it should not be used with the dot syntax.